# Possibly unhandled rejection with $q.reject

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, es6-promise

I'm using Angular with jasmine and got the error:

`Possibly unhandled rejection: {"body2":{}} thrown`

My code that's throwing the error:

```
createAccount() {
  // Return some ES6 Promise/async call with return value from test.
  return this.request({method: 'POST', body: {}})
      .catch(error => {
        if (error.flaky) {
            // Handle a specific error with another call
            return this.createDifferentAccount();
        }

        console.log('Passed the specific case');
        // Generically fail for other errors.
        this.$q_.reject(error);
      });
}
```

My jasmine test case for this (that is failing):

```
it('returns other errors', () => {
  const outerError = {
    body2: {},
  };
  spyOn(service, 'request')
      .and.returnValues($q.reject(outerError));

  const result = service.createAccount()
      .catch(() => {
        console.log('This is never called');
      });
  expect(result).toHaveBeenRejected();
  console.log('Neither is this');
});
```

How can I handle this error/what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're just rejecting the error, not returning the rejection.

The fix is pretty simple, change

`this.$q_.reject(error);`

to

`return this.$q_.reject(error);`

And remember to **always return a value from within a .then() or .catch() block!**